# Primefaces Datatable not correctly rendered after filter applied

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2

I have a Primefaces datatable that is inside an `accordionPanel`
Now when I added a filter to one column, datatable is no more correctly displayed correclty when filter applied.
When debugging, I can see that the `org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer` is called and it seems to work correctly (adding `tr` elements), but when I inspect the html in my browser, there are only inputs and plain text.
Here is the rendering of the datatable before filtering:

[image: Datatable before hitting the filter]

And here is the rendering of the datatable after selecting a filter value:

[image: Rendering after hitting the filter]

And here is a little bit of code that can reproduce the issue:

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true" id="someId" activeIndex="1">
   <p:tab title="title" id="tabId">
      <p:dataTable var="item" widgetVar="itemTbl" id="itemTbl" value="#{managedBean.items}" 
            filteredValue="#{managedBean.filtered}" style="margin-top:20px;">

          <p:column style="width: 129px !important">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Column1"></h:outputLabel>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>
          <p:column style="width: 101px !important" filterBy="name"
                filterOptions="#{managedBean.itemOptions}"
                        filterMatchMode="exact">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Column2"></h:outputLabel>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
  </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

I am using JSF 2.2 (Mojarra) and Primefaces 4.

Any help would be more than appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out the cause behind this weird behaviour:
My datatable was placed inside a `p:outputPanel` with `autoupdate` set to `true`.
I hope this will be of some help

Comment: thanks, i just changed autoUpdate to false and my datatable displayed as expected. saved me some heartache.

Comment: I'm happy this was of some help, it took me an entire night to figure it out :-P